# PHP: preg_replace replace abbreviation using backreferences

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'd like to perform a character replacement using `preg_replace` in PHP on the following string:

```
Dieser Text enthält diverse Akürzungen wie z.B., d.h., u.a. oder m.w.H.
```

The output should be like:

```
Dieser Text enthält diverse Abkürzungen wie z.\,B., d.\,h., u.\,a. oder m.\,w.\,H.
```

Currently I'm using this code:

```
<?php
$text = 'Dieser Text enthält diverse Akürzungen wie z.B., d.h., u.a. oder m.w.H.';

$searchFor = array(
    '/([a-z]\.)([a-z]\.)([a-z]\.)/i', // m.w.H.
    '/([a-z]\.)([a-z]\.)/i', // z.B.
);

$replaceWith = array(
    '\1\\,\2\\,\3',
    '\1\\,\2',
);

$replaced = preg_replace($searchFor, $replaceWith, $text);
?>
```

Is there a way to combine the two regular expressions?

When I'm using the following expression, I'm not able to use the matched character:

```
/([a-z]\.){2,}/i
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to find all single letter + dot `\b[a-z]\.` followed by an other single letter + dot.

you can use:

```
$txt = preg_replace('~\b[a-z]\.(?=[a-z]\.)~i', '$0\,', $txt);
```

where `(?=..)` is a lookahead that performs only a check (*followed by*)

Second solution:

```
$txt = preg_replace('~(?<=\b[a-z]\.)(?=[a-z]\.)~i', '\,', $txt);
```

Instead of a backreference to the whole match, I use a lookbehind `(?<=..)`. Nothing is captured and the regex engine is at the good offset to add `\,`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But unfortunately it gives me m.\,w.H. instead of m.\,w.\,H.

Comment: @Mark: and I don't know why! I have edited to a working solution.

Comment: Great! It's working now. As soon as I have enough reputation points I'll upvote your answer.